# SQL QUERY to find the all senior citizen from table

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]select * from patient where age as datediff(pdob,'2022-06-11')>=75;

why is this query is giving an empty set?

My question is:- Find all the patients who can avail of senior citizen discount.

Comment: Datediff returns the difference in days, and your expression would result in negative values. Try to select the Datediff expression without `WHERE`

Comment: `where datediff('2022-06-11', pdob) >= 75;`

Comment: @lemon your query outputs all rows.

Comment: @HoneyBadger can you please write the whole query... i am not getting that how can we check if we don't use where?

Comment: @RahulSrivastava I meant just to check your expression. If you wonder why your `WHERE` clause filters out all records, the best way to debug is to check if your expression gives the values you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of [`DATE_DIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) is that it outputs the difference in days. If you want a difference in years, you can use [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
SELECT * 
FROM patient 
WHERE DATE_ADD(pdob, INTERVAL 75 YEAR) < '2022-06-11'
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iDYbb2oakdwRZhw4wGyfNT/0).

Note: if you really want to use `DATE_DIFF`, you need to transform 75 years into days and use that value.